# Error while Execution android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have developed an calculator app. It needs two inputs num1 and num2.
When i give the 2 inputs the arithmetic process is working good. But, when i click any buttons(add,sub,mul,division) without any inputs, the app has closed and shows the error "Unfortunately calc has stopped.

```
public void onButtonClick(View v){
    EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText); 
    EditText e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2); 
    TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView); 
    float num1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString()); 
    float num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString()); 
    float sum = num1 + num2; t1.setText(Float.toString(sum));
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code..?

Comment: May be `NullPointerException` in `onClick()` of buttons, post your code

Comment: I bet it´s a simple solution, if we see your code, we can help fast ;)

Comment: `public void onButtonClick(View v) {
        EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        EditText e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        float num1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
        float num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
        float sum = num1 + num2;
        t1.setText(Float.toString(sum));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess its because you're having `null` value in the 'editText' and you're converting null value to float without checking for the condition that it is not null.
So before conversion. check if the editText is null. Like this:

```
if(e1.getText().toString()!="" && e2.getText().toString()!="")
{
    float num1 = Float.parseFloat(e1.getText().toString()); 
    float num2 = Float.parseFloat(e2.getText().toString());
}
```

And you should use 'Float' for conversion and not 'Int'

Comment: Check for empty as well, text box probably returns an empty string not a null.

Comment: If(e1.getText() != "").. Do this to both textboxes

Answer (score 1):

Just add a validation method before Onclick

```
    private boolean validation(){

    int error = 1;

    if(num1.getText().toString.equals("")){error = error + 1;}

    if(num2.getText().toString.equals("")){error = error + 1;}

    if(error == 0){return true;} else { return false; }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 String mNum1="",mNum2="";

    mNum1=e1.getText().toString();
    mNum2=e2.getText().toString();

  if(!mNum1.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !mNum2.equalsIgnoreCase("") )
  {

    float num1 = (float) Double.parseDouble(mNum1);
    float num2 = (float) Double.parseDouble(mNum2);
    float sum = num1 + num2;
    System.out.println("sum"+String.valueOf(sum));

    t1.setText(String.valueOf(sum));


    }
```